# A table is not displaying correctly my wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am currently working on my website where I have a table in place and the table is not displaying correctly. The texts are off by some pixels.

Here is the link to the site `http://bit. ly/xMaBXR`

Answer (score 1):

Are referring to the gap between the columns? If yes than check the table markup as its adding one more empty column in between those two columns which is resulting in the gap

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks really messed up, my recommendation is to strip out all the css from your table, and stop copying your code out of microsoft word it's really bad practice and it will wreck havoc in your code. Instead use an editor such as dreamweaver to create your tables. It has to be all that extra styles pulled through from word that is creating weird css issues on your site. You can find a converter if you don't want to do this, something like http://www.textfixer.com/html/convert-word-to-html.php

e.g. MsoNormal are word classes, also don't use 'pt' in your styles (margin, padding etc...) use 'px' (pixels) instead.